# Hiding an option from a select based on description

Tags: jquery

I am a little new to jquery, but I love the short compact and powerfull code.
I am trying to remove an option from a select that is fetched from a db. The values of the different options can differ, so I need to select from the description and not from the value. From other questions it seems like most solutions look at the value of the option, but in my case the value can change, but not the description.

Here is a sample output on the page:

```
<div class="entityPropertyValueEdit entityPropertyValueEdit_ProjectSelect col-sm-9">
<select propertyid="347" name="e_prop[347]" id="e_prop[347]" class="" rel="Project Select">
    <option value="80" selected="selected">Unknown</option>
    <option value="972">Manager</option>
    <option value="18325">Sales</option>
    <optgroup label="Branches Sales">
        <option value="1016">New York</option>
        <option value="1022">London</option>
        <option value="1028">Paris</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Optional Sales">
        <option value="1089">Dublin</option>
        <option value="1095">Hong Kong</option>
        <option value="1101">Berlin</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
</div>
```

I need to hide the option with description **Berlin**. The optgroup labels will always be the same. The div class name will always be the same (There can be multiple selects on the page) and the select rel will always be "Project Select". The optgroup labels are also constant.

Comment: $('.entityPropertyValueEdit_ProjectSelect select option')[8].remove()

I have found this to work,and using it for now,  but I am concerned that in the long run extra options could be inserted above it which would then hide the incorrect option.
I need to somehow get the [8] from Berlin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `filter` to hide your option.

```js
var hidetext = 'Berlin';
$('.entityPropertyValueEdit select option')
  .filter(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == hidetext)
      $(this).hide();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="entityPropertyValueEdit entityPropertyValueEdit_ProjectSelect col-sm-9">
  <select propertyid="347" name="e_prop[347]" id="e_prop[347]" class="" rel="Project Select">
    <option value="80" selected="selected">Unknown</option>
    <option value="972">Manager</option>
    <option value="18325">Sales</option>
    <optgroup label="Branches Sales">
      <option value="1016">New York</option>
      <option value="1022">London</option>
      <option value="1028">Paris</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Optional Sales">
      <option value="1089">Dublin</option>
      <option value="1095">Hong Kong</option>
      <option value="1101">Berlin</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you very much. Code is also done so it is easy to understand

Answer (score 2):

If you get the values from a database, that means you can use the description to set an alternate property for each `option` element.

Consider this example:

```
<option value="1101" data-description="Berlin">Berlin</option>
```

You can then select any element by attribute and hide it:

```
var description = 'Berlin';

$('option[data-description=' + description + ']').hide();
```

Hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I cannot change the html in the page, but I have a space to insert some html. I like the solution though, but would not be able to use it in this specific scenario.